# Simple ESP to ESP reading blink program not reading input voltage

Tags: esp8266, programming, esp32

One ESP32's 3v3 is connected to GPIO 26 of another ESP32.
The program is uploaded. The built-in LED lights for two seconds as expected. Then, it turns off. No matter what GPIO pin the 3v3 is connected to (besides 2), the LED remains off.

```
/*
 * ON Board LED GPIO 2
 */

#define LED 2
#define inPin 26

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Pins 34, 35, 36, 39 are input only
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  // Sanity check LED works
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(digitalRead(inPin));
  digitalWrite(LED, digitalRead(inPin));
}
```

Any reason this is happening? Grounds are connected. Simply trying to turn LED on/off if external voltage occurs at any GPIO pin (e.g., 26).

Comment: are you saying that you are attempting to power one ESP32 from the GPIO pin of another ESP32?

Comment: Have you connected the GND pins of the two ESP?

Comment: @jsotola .....no

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer yes

Comment: you have a serial.println() statement in your code ... please add the resuling printout to your post

Comment: "0" ad infinitum

Answer (score 0):

Arduino GPIO automatically set as inputs, so I assumed the same for ESP32. Once the `pinMode` of the input pin was set, it worked:

```
#define LED 2 // ON Board LED GPIO 2
#define inPin 26

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Pins 34, 35, 36, 39 are input only
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT); // <----------
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(digitalRead(inPin));
  digitalWrite(LED, digitalRead(inPin));
}
```